# Get the body of content referenced in an Entity Reference field in node

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type "event" which contains an entity reference to another content type "speaker". The speaker content type contains image and body fields. If I select a speaker for my event, I am only able to output a link to the speaker within the event node page. Is there a way I can output the image and body fields within the referenced speaker content in the event node page?

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

Content Type > Manage Display

Change Format to "Rendered Entity"

Comment: cool, this must be a new feature.